# Writing XSLT Templates

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I've started playing around with XSLT, and am having a few issues. I've managed to output my XML document using a series of value-of select instructions, but I'm really struggling when it comes to writing my XSLT templates myself.

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="lecturers.xsl"?>
<lecturers>
<lecturer>
        <name> 
             <title>Professor</title> 
        <first>Peter </first> <last>Quirk</last>
        </name>
        <teaching>
        <course code="CO3070">XML and the Web</course>
        <course code="CO3300"> Web Server Architectures</course>
    </teaching>
    <research>
        The application of Web protocols to Biology
    </research>
</lecturer>

<lecturer>
    <name> 
    <title>Doctor</title> 
    <first>Brian </first> <last>Johnson</last>
    </name>
    <teaching>
        <course code="CO9999">Computer Hacking</course>
        <course code="CO3300"> Web Server Architectures</course>
    </teaching>
    <research>
        Investigating the various complexities of Computer Hacking
    </research>
</lecturer>
```

Then, this is my XSL as it currently stands:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" />

 <xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>XML Week 7</title>
 </head>

  <body>
  <h1>Week 7: Lecturers file turned to XSL:Template</h1>

 <table border="1">
<tr>
    <th><b>Title</b></th>
    <th><b>Name</b></th>
    <th><b>Teaching</b></th>
    <th><b>Research</b></th>
</tr>

<tr>

    <td><xsl:value-of select="lecturers/lecturer/name/title" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="lecturers/lecturer/name/first" /><xsl:text>&#x20;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="lecturers/lecturer/name/last" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="lecturers/lecturer/teaching/course" /> and <xsl:value-of select="(lecturers/lecturer/teaching/course)[2]" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="lecturers/lecturer/research" /></td>

</tr>
 </table>

</body>

</html>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This does output the information I need into a table, but I've been instructed to create new templates to hold the lecturer element, and then the course children of that element. I might just be over-complicating things in my head, but I just cannot get it to work, whenever I try to apply a template to one of the td's I just get a parsing error in the browser. So, does anyone have any tips for me? Would be much appreciated, even some basic examples to explain how to get it working in my example would be superb. Cheers guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one template to create the result document structure e.g.

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>XML Week 7</title>
 </head>

  <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>

</body>

</html>
 </xsl:template>
```

then write further templates to create the content e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="lecturers">
  <h1>Week 7: Lecturers file turned to XSL:Template</h1>

 <table border="1">
<tr>
    <th><b>Title</b></th>
    <th><b>Name</b></th>
    <th><b>Teaching</b></th>
    <th><b>Research</b></th>
</tr>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="lecturer">
<tr>

    <td><xsl:value-of select="name/title" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="name/first" /><xsl:text>&#x20;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name/last" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="teaching/course" /> and <xsl:value-of select="(teaching/course)[2]" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="lecturers/lecturer/research" /></td>

</tr>
</xsl:template>
```

As you see, the templates do an `apply-templates` to keep up the processing.

[edit]
In response to your comment, if you want to use more templates for the different child or descendant elements of the `lecturer` element you can use

```
<xsl:template match="lecturer">
   <tr>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

and then write templates for the elements e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="name/title | research">
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name/first">
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ', ../last)"/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>

<!-- don't output name/last as the name/first template already does -->
<xsl:template match="name/last"/>

<xsl:template match="teaching">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="course"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="course">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:text> and </xsl:text></xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Okay, so once I've added the template match="lecturer" do I need to change the value-of selects inside the td's to make it into a template, or is that all I need? I'm just really confused by how this whole thing works, it's been pretty poorly taught to us tbh. Thanks.

Comment: You write a template to match a certain type of node, for instance an element node with name `lecturer` with `match="lecturer"` and inside the template you write expressions relative to the matched node as a context node. And of course you need to use `apply-templates` to make sure nodes are processed.

Comment: Okay, sorry to be a pain, but, as an example. If I wanted the title to appear using a template, how would I go about it? Would something like this work:

`<xsl:template match="lecturer">
<tr>
 
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="lecturer/name/title"/></td>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="lecturer" />
</tr>
</xsl:template>`

Answer (score 1):

Where you currenly have:

```
<tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="lecturers/lecturer/name/title" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="lecturers/lecturer/name/first" /><xsl:text>&#x20;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="lecturers/lecturer/name/last" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="lecturers/lecturer/teaching/course" /> and <xsl:value-of select="(lecturers/lecturer/teaching/course)[2]" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="lecturers/lecturer/research" /></td>
</tr>
```

You would want to have a call to `apply-templates` and have a `lecturer` template.

```
<xsl:template match="lecturer">
    <tr>

        <td><xsl:value-of select="name/title" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name/first" /><xsl:text>&#x20;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name/last" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="teaching/course" /> and <xsl:value-of select="(teaching/course)[2]" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="research" /></td>

    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```